# How to customize message for filesize exceed in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, filesize, multipart

I am working on SmartGwt application with file savings. My upload servlet accepts more than one file. If one of the files is exceeding filesize treshold, I will need to localize the file and send customized error message back then.

Servlet code:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        Collection<Part> files = request.getParts();
        for(Part obj : files)
        {
            if(PARAM_COMMAND_ITEM.equals(extractAttribute(obj, ATTR_NAME)) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(extractAttribute(obj, ATTR_FILENAME)))
            {
                getService().saveFile(obj.getInputStream(), extractAttribute(obj, ATTR_FILENAME).trim());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ex)
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error during import", ex);

        if(ex.getMessage().contains("exceed") && ex.getMessage().contains("max") && ex.getMessage().contains("filesize"))
        {
            sendMsg(response, CODE_ERROR_RESPONSE, "Filesize exceeded");
        }
        else
        {
            sendMsg(response, CODE_ERROR_RESPONSE, "Unknown error.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not associated with catching IllegalStateExceptions and checking its message.
My multipart configuration is placed in web.xml

```
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
    </multipart-config>
```

Is it possible to localize the file ? Can error messages be customized in any configuration file (web.xml - multipart conf, ...) ?

Comment: not to my knowledge, you are going to have to ask the servlet dev to localize the message for you, or do some magic with apache

Comment: I would like to localize both the file and the message in the servlet - that means find the exceeding file and customize message - example: "File 'exmaple.mp3' is exceeding maximus size of 2 MB" and also "Your package of mp3s is exceeding maximum size of 100 MB".